# How can the modulus of something be less than zero?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I've been asked to prove that for $\epsilon>0$,

$$| a-x| < \epsilon \iff a-\epsilon<x<a+\epsilon,$$

and as a hint to consider both $| x-a|>0$ and $| a-x|<0$.

I used the fact that for $| x-a|>0$, $|x-a|=x-a$ to prove it, and now want to consider $| x-a|<0$.

How can I express $| x-a|<0$ without the modulus sign, as I did with $| x-a|=x-a$ for $|x-a|>0$?

Comment: It's clearly a typo. Probably the hint was supposed to say 'consider both $(x-a)>0$ and $(x-a)<0$.

Answer (score 4):

The absolute value can't be negative. What the hint probably meant was to consider two cases: $x - a > 0$, in which we have $|a-x| = x - a$, and the other case $a-x > 0$, in which we have $|a-x| = a-x$. Can you do it now?